# how to make child class call parent class __init__ automatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i had a class called CacheObject,and many class extend from it.

now i need to add something common on all classes from this class so i write this

```
class CacheObject(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.updatedict = dict()
```

but the child class didn't obtain the updatedict attribute.i know calling super init function was optional in python,but is there an easy way to force all of them to add the init rather than walk all the classes and modify them one by one?

Comment: are you looking for a solution which should work correctly with multiple inheritence? if so, you must call `super` in any case.  If the subclasses don't define there own `__init__`, base-class's `__init__` is called automaticallye. Else, they must include a call to `super().__init__`.

Comment: "i know calling super init function was optional in python" -- not if you want the base class to have the freedom to run initialization code, it isn't.

Comment: if i reverse the control the subclass still need to be modified.all subclass __init__ must be rename.

Comment: How many classes do you have inheriting from CacheObject that you need to add the `super` line to? Although I like the concept behind this question, it seems like the motivation is a bit shady. Plus you only have to add the `super` *once* (to each class). That doesn't seem particularly onerous to me. And you know what they say - explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest a non-code fix:

Document that `super().__init__()` should be called by your subclasses before they use any other methods defined in it.

This is not an uncommon restriction. See, for instance, the documentation for [`threading.Thread`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) in the standard library, which says:

> If the subclass overrides the constructor, it must make sure to invoke the base class constructor (`Thread.__init__()`) before doing anything else to the thread.

There are probably many other examples, I just happened to have that doc page open.

Answer (score 10):

I was in a situation where I wanted classes to always call their base classes' constructor in order before they call their own. The following is Python3 code that should do what you want:

```
  class meta(type):
    def __init__(cls,name,bases,dct):
      def auto__call__init__(self, *a, **kw):
        for base in cls.__bases__:
          base.__init__(self, *a, **kw)
        cls.__init__child_(self, *a, **kw)
      cls.__init__child_ = cls.__init__
      cls.__init__ = auto__call__init__

  class A(metaclass=meta):
    def __init__(self):
      print("Parent")

  class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
      print("Child")
```

To illustrate, it will behave as follows:

```
>>> B()
Parent
Child
<__main__.B object at 0x000001F8EF251F28>
>>> A()
Parent
<__main__.A object at 0x000001F8EF2BB2B0>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a question when I'm using this. Can you please take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64753383/6699433

Comment: Hey @klutt, I checked out the answers over there: both are very good and accurate. My code does indeed make a bit of a mess, it will probably have to be tweaked a bit to prevent constructors from being called over and over again.

Comment: Welcome back. I was not sure that you were still around. But you should probably edit this answer to let others know that it is not as good as it looks.

Answer (score 4):

You can override `__new__`. As long as your base classes doesn't override `__new__` without calling `super().__new__`, then you'll be fine.

```
class CacheObject(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        instance.updatedict = {}
        return instance

class Foo(CacheObject):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

However, as some commenters said, the motivation for this seems a little shady. You should perhaps just add the super calls instead.

Comment: This is the cleanest answer in this thread.

Comment: Is`CacheObject.__new__` called _before_ the computation of `Foo.__init__` of _after_?

Comment: `__new__` creates an object, `__init__` is then called to initialise the object that was just created.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't what you asked for, but how about making `updatedict` a property, so that it doesn't need to be set in `__init__`:

```
class CacheObject(object):
    @property
    def updatedict(self):
        try:
            return self._updatedict
        except AttributeError:
            self._updatedict = dict()
            return self._updatedict
```

Hopefully this achieves the real goal, that you don't want to have to touch every subclass (other than to make sure none uses an attribute called `updatedict` for something else, of course).

There are some odd gotchas, though, because it is different from setting `updatedict` in `__init__` as in your question. For example, the content of `CacheObject().__dict__` is different. It has no key `updatedict` because I've put that key in the class, not in each instance.

Comment: If you used cached_property, you can just return empty dict. The moment it's accessed, it'll set the cache and then act just like regular attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of motivation, another option is to use `__init_subclass__()` (Python 3.6+) to get this kind of behavior. (For example, I'm using it because I want users not familiar with the intricacies of Python to be able to inherit from a class to create specific engineering models, and I'm trying to keep the structure of the class they have to define very basic.)

In the case of your example,

```
class CacheObject:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.updatedict = dict()

    def __init_subclass__(cls) -> None:        
        orig_init = cls.__init__

        @wraps(orig_init)
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            orig_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
            super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        
        cls.__init__ = __init__
```

What this does is any class that subclasses `CacheObject` will now, when created, have its `__init__` function wrapped by the parent class—we're replacing it with a new function that calls the original, and then calls `super()` (the parent's) `__init__` function. So now, even if the child class overrides the parent `__init__`, at the instance's creation time, its `__init__` is then wrapped by a function that calls it and then calls its parent.

Answer (score -2):

You can add a decorator to your classes :

```
def my_decorator(cls):
    old_init = cls.__init__
    def new_init(self):
        self.updatedict = dict()
        old_init(self)
    cls.__init__ = new_init
    return cls

@my_decorator
class SubClass(CacheObject):
    pass
```

if you want to add the decorators to all the subclasses automatically, use a metaclass:

```
class myMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, parents, dct):
        return my_decorator(super().__new__(cls, name, parents, dct))

class CacheObject(object, metaclass=myMeta):
    pass
```

Comment: All instances of `CacheObject` will share the _same_ dictionary - that's definitely not what the OP wants. He wants an instance attribute on each instance. Also, python3 doesn't use `__metaclass__` anymore, it's `class CacheObject(object, metaclass=myMeta)` now.