# Is it safe to use autocall __init__ in this way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, metaclass

I wanted to force children to call parent constructor and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50819088/6699433) which seems to do the job fine. However, I'm a bit unsure if what I'm doing is safe. I have this:

```
# Copied from answer linked above
class meta(type):
    def __init__(cls,name,bases,dct):
        def auto__call__init__(self, *a, **kw):
            for base in cls.__bases__:
                base.__init__(self, *a, **kw)
            cls.__init__child_(self, *a, **kw)
        cls.__init__child_ = cls.__init__
        cls.__init__ = auto__call__init__

# My code

import unittest

class TestBase(unittest.TestCase, metaclass=meta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.testvar="Hello, World!"
        

class A(TestBase):
    def foo(self):
        # Inherited from TestBase
        print(self.testvar)
        # Inherited from unittest.TestCase
        self.assertEqual("Hello, World!", self.testvar)

A().foo()
```

This prints "Hello, World!" as expected, and I'm able to use `assertEqual` from `unittest.TestCase`, but I have a feeling that I might be on very thin ice here. Is this safe to do? Can it collide with `unittest` in any way?

In the original post, `TestBase` did not inherit from `unittest.TestCase`. That's the difference.

Comment: unittest already has special rules regarding auto-running the classes (and therefore their init methods) - so take some care. Do you need this for actuall "unitest" things, or for general classes?

Comment: @jsbueno It is for unittests but I'm gonna skip the idea according to answers below.

Answer (score 4):

Here nothing's happening anyway, you only need to delegate back to the parent if you actually override the method, if you don't then the original method is not shadowed and will be called normally.

I'd strongly recommend not doing this though, especially for unittest as `__init__` is not actually of any use there: `unittest` only calls `__init__` to initialise test cases based on the method names it finds, the initialisation hook you want is `setUp` (and `tearDown` though `addCleanup` is usually safer and more reliable). You can define helper methods in test classes, but you should *not* instantiate testcases yourself.

Plus `unittest` is not great, it's quite verbose, the API surface is large, and the class-based design hampers the modularity (somewhat unexpectedly maybe). I'd strongly recommend taking a gander at `pytest`.

Answer (score 3):

Unittest apart (which meddles some of the rules for auto-running classes iteself), this code does a mess.

It will run the `__init__` methods of the classes several times over, in a hard to determine order.

here is what happens with your code when I add an intermediate class, with an actual collaborative  `__init__` calling `super()` (and take out `unittest` for sanity):

```
class meta(type):
    def __init__(cls,name,bases,dct):
        def auto__call__init__(self, *a, **kw):
            for base in cls.__bases__:
                base.__init__(self, *a, **kw)
            cls.__init__child_(self, *a, **kw)
        cls.__init__child_ = cls.__init__
        cls.__init__ = auto__call__init__

# My code



class TestBase(metaclass=meta):
    def __init__(self):
        print("base")
        self.testvar="hello"

class Middle(TestBase):
    def __init__(self):
        print("middle")
        super().__init__()

class A(Middle):

    def foo(self):
        # Inherited from TestBase
        print(self.testvar)
        # Inherited from unittest.TestCase

        assert self.testvar == "hello"

A().foo()
```

Will print:

```
base
middle
base
base
middle
base
hello
```

Doing this correctly would require the metaclass to:
check if the class being created have an `__init__` of itself and each `__init__` in the `__mro__`  (not `__bases__` these are only the immediate ancestors). For each `__init__` method, if it is not already wrapper, wrap it (the same as applying a decorator and replace the original method), that will make it mark an special flag on the instance once it is run, and skip running if it already have been called for the instance, and (the same wrapper) - call the next `__init__` in the mro at its exit.

This could ensure all `__init__` in the chain are run, even if one or more of them do not feature a  `super()` call  - but there are downsides: the superclasses `__init__` would only be called at the end of the child's run - and one `__init__` method would become special so it could not be manually called as an ordinary method (although that is rarely used - however, they'd become "special" in that respect).